# How to replace column values with values in another column based on condition?

Tags: pandas

If the "type" column value is tumor, I want to replace it with value in the "admin.disease_code" column.

Sample data:

|  | admin.disease_code | Col2 | Col3 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | hello | m | n | tumor |
| 1 | bye | o | p | a |
| 2 | thanks | q | r | b |

Expected output:

|  | admin.disease_code | Col2 | Col3 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | hello | m | n | hello |
| 1 | bye | o | p | a |
| 2 | thanks | q | r | b |

Code:

```
   # If "type" is tumor, replace with value in "admin.disease_code"

    meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan.loc[meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan["type"] == "tumor", "admin.disease_code"] = meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan.loc[meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan["admin.disease_code"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df
###
  admin.disease_code Col2 Col3   type
0              hello    m    n  tumor
1                bye    o    p      a
2             thanks    q    r      b
3               rock    a    z  tumor
```

```
df['type'] = np.where(
    df['type'] == 'tumor', 
    df['admin.disease_code'], 
    df['type']
)
df
###
  admin.disease_code Col2 Col3   type
0              hello    m    n  hello
1                bye    o    p      a
2             thanks    q    r      b
3               rock    a    z   rock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where:

```
import numpy as np
meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan['type'] = np.where(meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan["type"] == "tumor", meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan["admin.disease_code"], meth_clin_sub_nt_kipan['type'])
```

Comment: ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (1148)